# How to fetch CiViCRM events externally [ Drupal 7]

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home, rest

I'm new to CiViCRM. I want to fetch events which are created in CiViCRM which is hosted on another server. So basically I want to fetch CiViCRM data from one individual site to my site. I don't know that which are the ways to do it and which is the best one. But I think Rest option would be good if I'm not wrong. I'm not able to find any similar example which is near to my task. All I don't understand that how should I use my rest url with code:

1) Option 1:

$api = new civicrm_api3(array ('server' => 'http://localhost/abc',

'api_key'=>'123456789',
  'key'=>'123xyzABC'));

2) Option 2:

```
 $contactxml =       simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/abc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern /rest.php?entity=contact&action=get&key=<site    key>&api_key=$apikey&last_name=Koot");
  foreach ($contactxml->children() as $contact) {
    $display = $contact->display_name;
  }
```

Is there any other options. I want to go for option 1 if that is possible. How to get response in JSON?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $test = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/xyz/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/extern/rest.php/entity=Event&action=get&json="sequential":1}&api_key=123456789&key=123xyzABC');
print_r($test);exit; For above code I'm getting this:
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Result] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [error_message] => Failed to authenticate key [is_error] => 1 ) ) both keys are also correct. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @Xavier
I have tried that too:
module_load_include('php', 'civicrm', '../api/class.api'); $api = new civicrm_api3 (array ('server' => 'http://localhost/abc', 'api_key'=>'123456789', 'key'=>'123xyzABC')); if($api->Event->Get(array('sequential'=>1))) { // each key of the result array is an attribute of the api echo "\n contacts found " . $api->count; foreach ($api->values as $c) { echo "\n".$c->sort_name. " working for ". $c->current_employer; } // in theory, doesn't append
} else { echo $api->errorMsg();
}
exit; // */ It gives me:
**Unable to parse returned JSON**

Comment: Please edit your question or add comments when you have more information that could help resolve the problem. Answers should be reserved to describe a solution to the question asked.

Comment: @samuelsov , Sorry for that. I'm new here. I thought if I change my original question, how you guys know about that modifications? Is there any automated notification or something like that?

Comment: No problem. Usually people add a bold "Edit" below the original text. If the question become too much of a back and forth discussion, then IRC or forum.civicrm.org is a better place.

Answer (score 2):

Option one: API will be the best option

Please use this link in your instance 
http://localhost/abc/civicrm/api/explorer
or 
http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api/explorer#explorer

you will get JSON output

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already seen those links. All I don't understand is the code. As per this link:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/REST+interface First thing is to login: $test = simplexml_load_file("https://<your site>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?q=civicrm/login&name=Erik Hommel&pass=<password>&key=<site key>");
foreach ($test->children() as $kids) { $apikey = $kids->api_key; $sessionid = $kids->PHPSESSID;
} Query:
But what should be the value of "name" and "pass" parameters? Are those the credentials of a Drupal user with admin role (whic

Comment: yes,  name and pass are credentials of drupal user with admin right

Comment: @parthvora : Please first try getting the value in the browser (address bar)                 http://localhost/abc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&json={"sequential":1,"api_key":999}/drupal_test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&json={"sequential":1,"api_key":999}&api_key=999&key=123abc

Comment: I have tried below links directly into browser address bar as you suggested: http://localhost/abc/sites/all/modules/civicr ​m/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&json={"sequential":1,"api_key":123456789}&a ​pi_key=123456789&key=123xyzABC http://localhost/abc/sites/all/modules/civicr ​m/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&json={"sequential":1}&a ​pi_key=123456789&key=123xyzABC But I'm getting this: **Unable to parse returned JSON**

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to use a wrapper around that call that hide the complexity.

You can copy api/class.api.php into your client server and use it as indicated in the example in the source:

```
 $api = new civicrm_api3 (array ('server' => 'http://example.org',
                                'api_key'=>'theusersecretkey',
                                'key'=>'thesitesecretkey'));

if $api->Contact->Get(array(
 'contact_type'=>'Individual',
 'last_name' => 'koot',
 'return'=>'sort_name,current_employer')) 
{
  // each key of the result array is an attribute of the api
  echo "\n contacts found " . $api->count;
  foreach ($api->values as $c) {
    echo "\n".$c->sort_name. " working for ". $c->current_employer;
  }
  // in theory, doesn't append
} else {
  echo $api->errorMsg();
}
```

should fetch from the remote civicrm server and let you do the needed with the data on your client server